# Can't save edittext value in rotation change

Tags: android

I have layout that contain EditText. When I rotate my phone the value in EditText gone. I have try to use saveInstanceState but not working. The saveInstanceState succesfully save My EditText value, but the EditText.setText can't set to the value from saveInstanceState bundle. This is my code

Fragment

```
class HelpFragment : Fragment() {

private var _binding: FragmentHelpBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding

private var helpMessage: String? = ""

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    _binding = FragmentHelpBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return binding?.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    initViewClicked()
    helpMessage = savedInstanceState?.getString("helptext")
    if (!helpMessage.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        activity?.runOnUiThread {
            binding?.edtHelpMessages?.setText(helpMessage)
            Log.e("HelpFragment", "Help message $helpMessage")
        }
    }
}

override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    outState.putString("helptext", binding?.edtHelpMessages?.text.toString())
    Log.e("HelpFragment", "Save Instance Help message ${binding?.edtHelpMessages?.text.toString()}")
}

private fun initViewClicked() {
    binding?.layoutHelp?.setOnClickListener { hideKeyboard() }
}

private fun hideKeyboard() {
    val view: View? = activity?.currentFocus
    if (view != null) {
        val imm = activity?.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
    }
}
```

XML Code

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".ui.profile.faq.HelpFragment">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_help"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:focusable="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_help"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Tell us what happened"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:fontFamily="@font/pra_medium"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_help_detail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="We will reply back to you as soon as possible, maximum within 24 hours."
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:fontFamily="@font/pra_light"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_help"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_help_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:text="Your message"
            android:textSize="9sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorGrey"
            android:fontFamily="@font/pra_regular"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_help_detail"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_help_messages"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:fontFamily="@font/pra_regular"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:gravity="top|start"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:saveEnabled="true"
            app:backgroundTint="#29202020"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_help_message"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_submit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:text="Submit"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/edt_help_messages"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

How you have added that fragment to the activity?

If you have used `<fragment>` tag in xml to show that HelpFragment then try giving an `ID` attribute for the fragment tag..

If you have used fragment manager then try giving `tag name` when you add/replace fragment